# Crossing out the rest of a page in logbook document

Tags: spacing

I am creating a logbook for an engineering class in latex that includes all of my work for the semester. Currently, I just have a `\newpage` command after every entry to separate them. However, I would like to fill the empty area at the bottom of every page with something so that it looks like a paper logbook would. I am thinking a cross of some sort, but am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `tikz` for drawing and `notespages` for filling the rest of the page.

Below a command `\crossout` is defined, which can be used instead of `\newpage`. It crosses out the rest of the page using `\notesfill`. The latter is set up to draw nothing in case there is only little room left on the page (see option `fillminspace` (default value: `0.25\textheight`)). For additional information see comments in code.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{notespages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definenotesstyle{crossout}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[color=gray]
        % should always be used
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,\remainingtextheight);
        % draw what ever you want here
        \draw[very thick] (0,0) -- (\textwidth,\remainingtextheight);
        \draw[very thick] (0,\remainingtextheight) -- (\textwidth,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\crossout}{%
    \notesfill[%
        titlestyle=none,            % no title
        notesstyle=crossout,        % draw a cross
        filltopskip=2ex,            % some distance between cross and text
        fillminspace=0.1\textheight % don't draw a cross, if remaining
                                    % space on page is less then 0.1\textheight 
    ]%
    \newpage % needed in case nothing is drawn
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\crossout

\lipsum[1-2]

\crossout

\lipsum[1-2]

Some more text here to fill the page just enough to get less then
0.1\verb|\textheight| of remaining space. This needs more then two
lines here.

\crossout

\end{document}
```